# client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /127.0.0.1:8032

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, resourcemanager

I want to run map reduce job with:

```
bin/hadoop jar wc.jar WordCount /user/hadoop/input /user/hadoop/output
```

As see in picture, The execution gets stuck in connecting to the resource manager and I don't have any error. [image: picture]
Using `jps`, `Resource Manager` is running but also `localhost:8032` can not works on the browser. 
`yarn-site.xml`:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
    <value>127.0.0.1:8032</value>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
    <value>127.0.0.1:8030</value>
    </property>
    <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
    <value>127.0.0.1:8031</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Please help me how to run jar properly.

Comment: 8032 isn't a web port - set `yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address`, or use port 8088, the default

Comment: You ideally should also replace `127.0.0.1` with the output of `hostname -f`

Comment: Do you say replace `yarn.resourcemanager.address` with `yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address` ?

Comment: No, add an extra property if you want to overwrite the YARN webapp address. But the actual port is 8088, by default. 8032 will never load a browser window

Comment: Blew up for me when I had ```job.setJar().``` in my code